# Is there any way to set jdbc query timeout globally in java project

Tags: java, oracle, prepared-statement, datasource, query-timeout

Can we set Query timeout globally (i.e. in DataSource configure, spring application properties file or somewhere).As i have to write everywhere in my project in which Statement / PreparedStatement used.

I have seen only two ways to set query timeout yet. But it works only one preparedStatement/statement at a time. see below code.

```
preparedStatement.setQueryTimeout(30); or PoolUtilities.setQueryTimeout(preparedStatement, 30);
```

I could not found any solution for this. Please let me know if you know to set simple jdbc query timeout on global level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_READ_TIMEOUT` for Oracle thin driver. Add to datasource as follows

```
properties.put(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_READ_TIMEOUT, readTimeoutMillis.toString());
dataSource.setConnectionProperties(properties);
```